# Using hover() with each() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table which contains a single row with even tds. Half of them are *remove from list* data and the other half for *add to list* data.

So the structure in my razor view is somewhat like

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover dataTable" 
       role="grid" aria-describedby="example2_info">
    <tbody>
        @{int j = 0;}
        @foreach (var i in item.Data)
        {
            { j++; }
            <tr role="row" class="odd">
                <td class="sorting_1 remove-from-list_@j" style="word-break:break-all;">
                ...
                <td class="add-from-list_@j">
            ...
```

So each class is getting dynamically name given.

My jQuery function, is as follows:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".table.table-bordered.table-hover.dataTable td.add-from-list")
           .not(':first').each(
            function (i) {
                $(".add-from-list_" + i).hover(function () {
                    $(this).css("background", "#fff2cc");
                })
            },
            function (i) {
                $(".add-from-list_" + i ).css("background", "");

            });
        $(".table.table-bordered.table-hover.dataTable td.remove-from-list").each(
            function (i) {
                $(".remove-from-list_" + i).hover(function () {
                    css("background", "#fff2cc");
                })
            },
            function (i) {
                $(".remove-from-list_" + i).css("background", "");
            });
```

It is not working.

Comment: A side node for you: I think you should check your html code. They are some errors there. Maybe there are the source of your trouble.

Comment: You're passing two functions to `each.` [I don't see any documentation for doing that](http://api.jquery.com/each/). When things don't work (or even before), the documentation should be your first port of call.

Comment: I don't see any `td` with the class `add-from-playlist` in your HTML. I see ones with `add-from-playlist_0` and such, but those won't match the selector you're using. All due respect, the problem above just needs debugging using the powerful debugger built into your browser. It may also be a good idea to step back from this task and work through some jQuery tutorials. There's no need for each `td` to have its own `add-from-playlist_0` class, for instance.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for the advice, sir.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was doing all this because I have a single row and many tds.(And this repeats, so variable j acts like a global variable) I don't want to break it into 2 trs.

Your last line says there is no need for each td to have its own add-from-playlist_0 class. Not each td will have this class. only some.

Comment: I have figured out the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You really should use CSS for your hover effect!!!

```
td[class^="add-from-list_"]:hover,
td[class^="remove-from-list_"]:hover{
    background: #fff2cc;
}
```

'^' means that the class starts with the string between the quotes.